# How to send touch events (Screen Events) to another app in android

Tags: android, events, touch

I am trying to develop an image processing based PowerPoint controller app on Android. My app will run in background and will find out hand actions.

My Android app captures images from camera and tries to find out left or right movement of hand, based on the action I want to send swipe-left/swipe-right to office suite application (which is displaying a ppt).

I know that there is a way to send gestures to android app using

adb shell input swipe 400 200 300 200

but that is not working from inside android app.

Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Some code snippets on how you are handling the touch events..

Comment: Office suite app needs swipe-left and swipe-right gestures for slide left/right. We can do it using Robot API in java but the same is not working with android for other apps.

Comment: If you want to develop a powerpoint controller (cool idea, btw!) couldn't you just send the "next-slide"-Command directly to the projecting computer instead sending the gesture to the app, which will send the "next-Slide"-Command?

Comment: We want the user to carry his pendrive and phone with ppt file in it, without having to carry laptop for projection